# How to embed csv in iframe if excel did not have embed function-Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I wish to embed CSV/Excel in Iframe, which allow user to edit and save the content, but in my server, the embed function have being turn off, anyone can share me ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the contents of csv in a textarea for editing without embedding:

```html
<textarea name="csv_content" rows="5" cols="33">
{{ csv_content }}
</textarea>
```

If you are more particular about the graphical part and want the csv contents in a table,
then you can use [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute:

```html
<table contenteditable="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row1 Column1</td>
            <td>Row1 Column2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```